# how can display any variable contant integer value is_int()?

Tags: php, variables, return-value, isinteger

I have this code:

```
$showCountSql    = "select cad_count from counteraccountdtl WHERE cad_userid =".$_SESSION['UID']." LIMIT 1";
$showCountresult = mysql_query($showCountSql);
$showCountrow    = mysql_fetch_array($showCountresult);
$newCount        = $showCountrow[cad_count];

if(is_int($newCount))
 echo "Value  is Integer";
else
 echo "Value not Integer";
```

I am fetching the value from MySql as "cad_count integer(5)", then I check whether this value is an integer or not and show the "Value not Integer" accordingly. What's wrong in it?

Comment: You can always use `var_dump($newCount)` to see exactly what the variable's type is, along with contents.

Comment: For completness to the answers, `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array of strings. See docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 2):

Use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/is_numeric) or [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit). These functions test if the given variable is a valid representation of a number or contains only digits.

[`is_int`](http://php.net/is_int) tests if the variable's type is `int`, and mysql_fetch* functions return integers as strings.

Answer (score 0):

`is_numeric()` is better for you. To make is_int() work, you have to make int value from old one

```
$var = intval($var);
```